# How to slide highcharts?

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I want to make a slider that shows up different charts after some time or on mouse click. (Just like an image slider.)

How to do that??
I know jQuery little bit but I dont know how to implements this.

EDIT:

I am experimenting with setInterval method on load event.

But, When I pull data from xml files, my code does not work. But, if I put explicit values rather than the xml file, the codes works exactly as I want.
I am pasting my code here.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    makeChart('data1.xml');


    function makeChart(file) {

        var options = {

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: '',
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second                            
                        setInterval(function() {

                            makeChart('data2.xml');
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit Consumption'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'}]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.percentage + ' %';
                }
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },

            series: []

        };

        $.get(file, function(xml) {

            // Split the lines
            var $xml = $(xml);

            options.chart.type = ($xml.find('type').text());

            // push categories
            $xml.find('categories item').each(function(i, category) {
                options.xAxis.categories.push($(category).text());
            });

            // push series
            $xml.find('series').each(function(i, series) {
                var seriesOptions = {
                    name: $(series).find('name').text(),
                    data: []
                };

                // push data points
                $(series).find('data point').each(function(i, point) {
                    seriesOptions.data.push(
                    parseInt($(point).text()));
                });

                // add it to the options
                options.series.push(seriesOptions);
            });
            var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    }
});​
```

Comment: dude at least try something before asking

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read about:

`setTimeout()` - to run slide after some time

`.click()` - it's event which run when you click some selector

`animate()` - if you want to your slider works fluently

`css: left,right,top,bottom` - you can change this attributes in `animate` to make slide effect

`css: position: absolute` - on elements which you want slide

`css: position: relative, overflow:hidden` - on element which contain your element in slider.

I think this thinks can be helpful to you. You can also find more examples of sliders in google. Just search.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thank you.. I dont want css methods because I want to redraw the charts instead of hiding and showing. I have pasted the code. please help..